# Concern of Python application Being stolen by other developers

Tags: python, docker, docker-secrets

**Context-**
I have a python script which takes in webcam video face as input and does some operations to the face to verify the person. I will forward this script to the android developers who will put this script to their app. The client advised me to secure my script so that they don't have the permission to use it outside of this gig(in their future projects). Also the developers asked me to containerize the script to that it acts as an API where they just provide the input video and out comes the desired output.

**Solution-**
I can make the script into a docker container and upload the image on dockerhub or AWS.

**Problem-**
It the developers are able to download the image and make a container from it, they will be able to use it in their future project (which defeats the purpose). How do I make sure that the container can only be used for an specific app? Which feature of docker allows me to do monitor or limit the usage of this image?

P.S-
I have limited knowledge of docker(I am learning along the way) so please tell me best approach to this problem.

Comment: If "they" will have access to the image (or the code in any sense), the answer is an ironclad contract with a suitably large damages clause. Everything can always be reverse-engineered.

Comment: Why not put the logic in a server backed by flask/django/fastapi? And control access via project_id and access_key?